# Can Artificial Expansion of Space Facilitate Dark Energy

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, energy, faster-than-light

Granted, not much is known about Dark Energy. Indeed, it may not even exist.

What we know is that something is driving the expansion of space (understanding we do not live in a [Hubble bubble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubble_bubble_(astronomy))). This expansion is either:

1. A property intrinsic to space; or
2. Energy liberated from the collision, and subsequent annihilation of virtual particles.

Beyond this, we do not know much else. For the sake of simplifying scientific adherence, I have averaged these two explanations. For the sake of this questions we know that when space expands, dark energy is responsible.

Assume that technology exists which is capable of contracting space (a feat that is understood to be obtainable employing highly-dense matter rotating at incredible speeds).

If we can put strain on space symmetrically, creating a negative gradient of space, will space about which this gradient is centered expand? If so, is this expansion the result of dark energy or the generation of dark energy?

EDIT:
Imagine you had a torus made of some [degenerate matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_matter), be it [strange matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strange_matter), [neutronium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutronium), or even a black hole. All of this stuff is really, really dense. We know that things that are dense, or otherwise heavy generate appreciable gravitational fields via *bending* of space-time.

If anything with a positive mass travels at a velocity approaching the speed of light (technically any non-zero velocity), the object begins to experience time-dilation when space-time resists this velocity.

As such, the idea is, if we take something really dense and spin it around a torus at speeds approaching the speed of light, we should be able to generate some pretty significant gravitational waves. If you cleverly arrange several tori into a sphere, you could create a region of space in the center of the sphere that is forced to expand (as space is pulled onto the surface of the sphere). Sort-of like a fictional Dyson Planet, where gravity is only on the surface of the planet.

NOTE: This is my first post, I am writing a novella and doing some world-building first. I can migrate to physics if this board isn't appropriate. Thanks!

Comment: I think this question is more appropriate for the physics stack.

Comment: But isn't it to theoretical? I don't really know what questions are tackled in the physics stack but this seems to assume to much for it.

Comment: There are too many fictional assumptions in this question, but more to the point, I don't know why this is about worldbuilding (VTC OT:NAW).  Why is the [tag:faster-than-light] tag even involved?  Is this leading to a dark energy engine?  If so, are you asking if such an engine is scientifically plausible?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Soan, the physics stack deals with math.  Fictional/theoretical is irrelevant so long as there's supporting equations.  Part of the problem here is that the author sounds like he's authoritative, but the question doesn't feel like it's based on math.  There's a disconnect I can't quite put my finger on.

Comment: @JBH To be honest, whether there's math or not in a question is completely irrelevant for Physics Stack Exchange. Many of the best questions there are purely conceptual.

Comment: @HDE226868, then may I suggest this question be migrated?  It reads more like something that would tickle their fancy than a worldbuilding question.

Comment: @HDE226868, unless you have an answer.  You might be the only participant on WB.SE who could answer this question.

Comment: liquid hydrogen, welcome to Worldbuilding Stack Exchange. I would recommend you make some clarifications before we do anything here. 1) What do you mean by "negative gradient of space"? 2) What do you mean by "contracting space"? 3) I think there's a lot of words in here that don't actually mean anything scientific (technobabble, I guess). The last paragraph seems kinda confusing to me; can you reshape it somehow?

Comment: To clarify, this question was posed as I am trying to develop some underlying theory justifying a fictional FTL drive.

Comment: It is well known that our universe has an underlying "aether" (or framework), comprised of space-time. Trivially, mass and velocities approaching c generate gradients or "wells" in spacetime. A gradient is just a change in magnitude, if space is bent by an object with positive mass, this is a positive gradient (canonically this contraction of space is referred to a gravitational well). Hope this helps the technobabble!

Comment: Dark energy has many more proposals than just those two. You assume that the strains on space are "symmetrical," which I assume you believe that a positive gradient here at position X yields a negative gradient at position -X. This isn't exactly a great assumption, but it has been proposed as a candidate of Dark Energy via MOND (Modified Newtonian Dynamics).

Comment: I think your question may be better boiled down to: if we take two very attractive masses and place them close enough, may the net gravitational forces between them (their own respective, inward pulls on space) be negative? The answer to that is no. When we introduce frame-dragging to the mix? Uhhh. I'm not sure, but my gut says also no.

Comment: I'd really like to know where you came up with your final assumption, perhaps a reference or a pointed finger in the right direction. If the question's status is resolved, it may help for an answer.